# Attaching wires to a socket

Tags: wiring, lamp

I have a floor lamp with an unwired lamp socket. I've taken the pieces apart so I now have a) the exposed wiring (see below) and b) the lamp socket where the exposed wiring needs to connect to (see below).

The problem is that I can't connect the exposed wiring to the lamp socket because it is not thick enough / doesn't have anything to stick to. In the original design, the exposed wiring was covered by copper sheaths (see below) which I believe made it easier to connect into the lamp socket, but those have been ripped off.

What are my options here to connect the wiring again? Do I need to buy new copper sheaths and try to wrap around the exposed wiring? Can I just try to bunch up the exposed wiring to make it thicker and try to make it stick? Should I hire an electrician? Is there something else I can do?

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Exposed Wiring]
[image: Lamp Socket]
[image: Copper Sheaths]

Comment: Can just use wire nuts(look like little plastic dunce hats), strip the wires and place the nuts on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word for that would be **ferrule**, which are a European thing, and might also be seen on "cheap Chinese" items which mimic European designs.

You could obtain some appropriate ferrules and a crimp tool and give it a try.  My best hope is that the 4 holes are "back-stab" connectors designed to grab either a ferrule, or a wire of certain size. Note the rectangular "release mechanism" holes nearby - don't overstress that or you will fatigue the spring and it won't hold anymore and will arc.

It's also possible these are not ferrules at all, and are part of a brass terminal meant to be crimped onto a wire, and that part has been [rent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rend) and broken off.  If so, the socket is scrap. But this sort of socket should be readily available as a whole assembly.

Comment: Agree--- those are ferrules (I'm certain.. you can see the crimps).     The wire underneath has gotten so hot that it oxidized and basically 'rusted' through.   This is gods way of saying "Throw this away and get an LED lamp".